# Unable to install php7.2-gd due to dependencies in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I would like to ask for help on installation of php7.2-gd. I've been trying to install this for 2 days but failed due to unmet dependencies. What I had tried so far are the following:

- Tried to install the dependencies (Failed)
- Changed repository, did the update and then tried installing dependencies (Failed)
- Tried downloading the .deb file from the site but it downloads incomplete size (Failed)
- Followed what these suggestions (Failed)
  -- [Unable to install packages due to dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1019794/unable-to-install-packages-due-to-dependencies)
  -- [Cannot install PHP7.2-dev on Ubuntu 18 due to unmet dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048568/cannot-install-php7-2-dev-on-ubuntu-18-due-to-unmet-dependencies)

There's probably a solution that I haven't tried yet, please help me guys, thanks!

Hi guys, here are some images:

[This is the error I got when trying to install php7.2-gd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiPrT.jpg)

[This is the error I got when trying to install the dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8vf3.jpg)

[I just noticed today that the downloaded packages from Ubuntu site were all incomplete and same in size = 1.9Kb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDfEQ.jpg)

Comment: Summaries don't help much, since you're having problems with the details. Please edit your question to include as much detail as we need to help you. (We don't know how much that is either)

Comment: It would be better if you include the output of `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install php7.2-gd` to the question (or to pastebin if it is long).

Comment: Sure, I'll edit my post